# Date difference between 2 sheets (One to Many relation)

Tags: date, powerbi, one-to-many, difference, date-difference

I'm a real noob in Power Bi, so this may be super trivial.

I have 2 sheets which are connected by SerialNumber. In sheet 'IDs' I have a list of each 'SerialNumber' and their 'ManufacturingDate'.

In the 'EVENTS' sheet I have multiple rows with the same 'SerialNumber' and in each row there is the 'MtxDate' and 'componentID' changed during the event.

I want to have a column which I can see the age of the 'SerialNumber' when a specifi event happened and a 'componentID' was changed, so I would need to have the difference between the 'MtxDate' and the 'SerialNumber' 'ManufacturingDate'.

Whenever I try to create a column or measure to do this, I do it in the 'EVENTS' sheet, but the 'ManufacturingDate' does not appear available. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you edit the question and post the sample data pictures?

Comment: Hi @balaji, it's sensitive data, so I can't. But I found out how to do it. Basically I had to create a new column (measure don't seem to work, I don't know why) and use RELATED to be able to access other sheets information.